# Window function isn't correctly summing over partition by column

Tags: sql, sqlite, window

I have two datasets: shipments and bills. I can't figure out how to paste excerpts of csv tables on StackOverflow, so here are images.

Shipments

[image: shipments table excerpt]

Bills

[image: bills table excerpt]

I'm trying to run a window function that sums all actual_amount by shipment.id using the following query:

```
SELECT 
    *
    , sum(actual_amount) OVER
         (PARTITION BY shipments.shipment_id) as costs
FROM shipments JOIN bills ON shipments.shipment_id = bills.shipment_id
```

When I run this query, the costs column shows incorrect sums:

[image: query output]

The costs column only sums the last two actual_amount of each shipment_id and doesn't sum correctly. I feel like I'm missing something basic here. I'm basically trying to create an Excel SUMIF function in SQL, whereby the actual_amount is the sum range and the shipment_id is the criteria.

Comment: Sum always requires a group by, if you omit it then it summarize to the detail level

Comment: It looks like your partition is aggregating to the shipping_id level. It has a one to many relationship.  Just use sum and group by and remove the partition

Comment: SELECT 
    , sum(actual_amount) actual_amount 
FROM shipments JOIN bills ON shipments.shipment_id = bills.shipment_id group by shipments.shipment_id

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! The issue is that the bills table has commas for any number > 1000. I removed the formatting from the table and the window function now functions correctly.
[correct output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/To39F.png)